# overloaded less than (<) operator for sorting objects in several ways

Tags: c++, c++11

If a class has overloaded an operator to facilitate sorting its objects by a particular attribute, is there a way to overload the operator again to sort by another attribute?

For example, the class below has overloaded `operator<` to compare its data member minutes, is there a way to do the same for its data member hours or would I just be better off creating a binary predicate for each sorting criteria? Thanks in advance.

```
class PhoneCall {
  friend ostream& operator<<( ostream&,const PhoneCall& );
  private:
      int minutes;
      int hours;

  public:
      PhoneCall(int = 0);
      bool operator<(const PhoneCall&);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const PhoneCall& p) {
   out << "Phone call lasted " << p.minutes << " minutes" << endl;
   return out;
}

PhoneCall::PhoneCall(int ct) {
    minutes = ct;
}

bool PhoneCall::operator<(const PhoneCall& p) {
    bool less = (minutes < p.minutes)? true: false;
    return less;
}
```

Comment: The answer is no. You cannot overload it in several different ways for an object. The `sort` function can have an additional parameter for the comparison function. I suggest you look into that.

Comment: @Ely Great! thank you.

Comment: `bool less = (minutes < p.minutes)? true: false;` — this code makes no sense, and is an anti-pattern: you’re effectively saying “if this is condition is true then set the result to true, else set it to false”. You *should* be saying: “set the result to the value of this condition”. In other words: `bool less = minutes < p.minutes;`. And once you’ve done this, the temporary variable becomes completely redundant, so just say `return minutes < p.minutes;` directly. That’s the conventional implementation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you for the explanation

Comment: As an approximation, if a proposed `<` doesn't do what would be synthesised from C++20's `auto Foo::operator <=>(const Foo &) = default;`, it shouldn't be called `<`, and instead should have a name describing what it does order by.

Answer (score 2):

You can also present extra friend functions that provide alternative sorting methods, and in c++11 you can define them inplace:

```
class PhoneCall {
 friend ostream& operator<<( ostream&,const PhoneCall& );
 private:
  int minutes;
  int hours;

 public:
  PhoneCall(int = 0);
  bool operator<(const PhoneCall&);
  friend bool LessTime(const PhoneCall& L, const PhoneCall& R)
  {  return L.minutes+L.hours*60 < R.minutes+R.hours*60; }

};

std::vector<PhoneCall> calls;
std::sort(calls.begin(), calls.end(), LessTime);
```

Also, you can overload the comparator on ordered containers such as set:

```
std::multiset<PhoneCall, LessTime> timeSet;
```

The use of an inline friend here, compared to a public static method is of minimal benefit. The real benefit of inline friend is when doing operator overloads, such as `operator <<`

Comment: @O'Neil You can declare friend functions inside classes in this style. They are closer to "static" functions, which you can also use in this way. But you are right they are not members... quick edit...

Answer (score 0):

No, what you want is not possible. Instead, `std::sort` provides two overloads. One that uses `operator<` by default and an overload which takes a functor for the comparison:

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

This can be used as such:

```
std::vector<PhoneCall> calls;
std::sort(calls.begin(), calls.end(), [](const PhoneCall& lhs, const PhoneCall& rhs) {
    return lhs.hours < rhs.hours;
});
```

Notice the lambda function as the third parameter does compare by hours.

Comment: Note that `minutes` and `hours` are **private** members.

Comment: Great! Thank you for clarifying and showing an example. I will explore further.

Comment: @O'Neil True, that's trivially fixable though.